# How to set edge preferences as command line arguments for edge browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

piece of code:
for chrome :

chrome_pref = set_browser_preference(webdriver, 'Chrome', dwnld_pref_flag)
context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=chrome_pref)

but for edge:
edge_pref = set_browser_preference(webdriver, 'Edge', dwnld_pref_flag)
context.driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), ***options=edge_pref**)

warning shown as remove the argument.
what exactly im  missing could you please support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue (remove the argument?). In your code, there seems to be some problem, eg:

```
context.driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), *options=edge_pref)
```

What is the `*` symbol in this line? Error in post editing?

Second, I'm not sure about the version of webdriver_manager you're using, it might also have some issues like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418721/initialising-msedge-browser-in-python-getting-typeerror-level-not-an-integer-o).

I created a simple demo, it works well:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

edgeOption = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.add_argument("start-maximized")
edgeOption.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=20).install(),options=edgeOption)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

If I've misunderstood something, please provide more details, such as a code sample that reproduces the problem, and any error messages.

Comment: HOOK-ERROR in before_feature: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'EdgeOptions'

Comment: thrown with this error please

Comment: here is the code

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.edge import service

from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge,EdgeOptions


edgeoptions = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeoptions.use_chromium = True
edgeoptions.add_argument("start-maximized")
edgeoptions.binary_location = r"C:\skfbearingselect_Wip\utilities\Drivers\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), options=edgeoptions)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")